# Keyword var performance for compilation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, resharper, var

Refactoring a big project (in term of code lines) I got to know ReSharper and the topic using var instead of the type which will only affect in compilation time.
Does it makes a big impact in the compilation time? I would like to define a code style for it in my company but i am not sure myself if I like the idea of "overusing" the keyword var...

Comment: I haven't ever heard of `var` having effects on compilation time. Technically, being it not-longer to any other common and uncommon type (`var` is 3 characters, `int` is 3 characters, but for example `string` is 5, so 66% longer than `var`, and surely `Dictionary<string, MyObject>` is even longer), it should make source code smaller, so faster to load by the compiler .

Comment: I think it is your choice, use var or not. We discuss this problem in our company, but don't meet single agreement.

Comment: I don't think it affects compile time appreciably, but I do have some strong opinions on the overuse of the `var` keyword...

Comment: @Ron Yep me too... in fact, I'm quite strict on when to use it...

Comment: @RonBeyer, I'm he opposite: I have strong views on its under-use. I am very strict on var always being used except for edge-cases.

Comment: @DavidArno I don't want to hijack this so I'd be happy to discuss it in a chat, but I once had a 40+ project solution that had one return type of a method change and it broke a lot of code, `var` wouldn't have caught that at compile time so the programmer would have let the check-in slip through (admittedly we didn't have great unit testing procedures at the time), but I'd rather catch it before having to run 5-6 hours of unit tests.

Comment: @DavidArno: using `var` always can lead to confusion and to additonal lookups which costs time and possiblly careless mistakes if you mix up types(f.e. `IEnumerable<string>` with `IEnumerable<char>`). You often have compiling code which breaks at runtime.

Comment: The only place I can think of where "var" would be a problem is in a print publication where the reader can't hover their mouse over the variable to find out what it is. "var" is a huge time and space saver. When I change my mind about a type somewhere way down deep in my code, I don't have to "fix" everything above it because it fixes itself. If you want to be pedantic about it and hand-approve all of the fallout, then I could see disallowing var so that each ripple effect would force a human to put eyes on it, but decent test coverage would let you know if there were any harmful effects.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `var` is not dynamic thus its type is known at compile-time. I have never encountered, and cannot begin to think of, a genuine scenario where using var, rather than explicitly stating the type, could cause code to compile, but fail at runtime.

Comment: @DavidArno: It's known to the compiler but often not to the developers. Even if everything works perfectly today it could be that you or somebody else need to maintain it. Then it's much easier to see the types beforehand. Having said that, `var` on obvious types is a wonderful way to reduce code and to prevent horizontal scrolling.

Comment: basically we have no big impact due to the fact that we are dealing with a non dynamic variable, the var key cloud be misleading. Different thing is the use of var in javascript, in this case we are dealing with a dynamic variable, the impact on the code is certainly much more relevant in this case.

Comment: There is a scenario where the code could be slower: wrong overutilization of `var`... A programmer could be tempted to replace `string foo;` (note, declaration only) with `var foo`... Then he sees that the code doesn't compile and so what he does? `var foo = ""` and he introduces an useless initialization (worse would be the case of `var focoll = new List<Foo>()` instead of `List<Foo> focoll`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, any difference is negligible to unobservable. I can find no difference whatsoever, even on larger projects. Whatever difference var makes is statistically insignificant, and lost amid the rest of the compilation work.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make any impact because type of var is get resolved at compile time as C# is static language.

---

At compile time compiler replaces actual type where var in code. So there is small impact on the compiler compiling code

Example:

```
var s = "hi";
```

gets replaced by

```
string s = "hi";
```

Comment: I still don't think its appreciable, but the differences are much more pronounced when the compiler has to walk a call hierarchy to figure out the return type. Think nested generic methods...

Comment: Surely it still has to figure out the return type so it can check that the expression on the RHS is the same type or can be converted to the type declared on the LHS?